# User adding irrelevant tags

Tags: discussion, editing, flagging, suggested-edits, specific-user

There have been a couple days now when at around the same time, a certain user has been going through old posts marked with the 'probability' tag and editing them to add irrelevant tags, most commonly changing 'probability' to 'probability-theory' when it is not necessary and adding the tag 'coin-flipping', a tag which does not really add any insight into the mathematical content of the post. I have attempted to report this user to moderators by flagging some posts the user has edited for moderator attention, but as of today, the user continues to fill the review edits queue with superfluous tag edits. Is there a way of preventing this user from doing so many edits or a better way of flagging the user for moderator attention?

Comment: Sounds like a badge-hunter. While bearing a diamond badge-hunters have nearly replaced rep-farmers as the pet peeve of mine. Good to have a discussion about what to do with such users, because otherwise I may overreact. Some of them do tidy up the site, some others...

Comment: I dunno.  As long as the tag is mathematically relevant, then I do not see the harm.  By "relevant," I mean that someone searching for the question/answer could do so using the tag.  OTOH, if someone desperate for a badge is deleting perfectly good tags and replacing them with ridiculous ones, then we have a serious problem.

Comment: It looks like someone just coined the *coin-flipping* tag and started adding it to questions. I don't see how that helps anyone else. I do admit that it may be overreacting from my side to assume that the tag was invented for the sole purpose of earning a taxonomist badge. Waiting for more opinions before I act.

Comment: @RonGordon [tag:probability] and [tag:probability-theory] are mutually exclusive. One is for elementary questions, the other for advanced ones. ( ( ([Yes, the names could be better.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1686/10014)) So the tags are *not* correct here.

Comment: My fault. They didn't do anything yesterday, so I thought/hoped it was a one-off and a message was unnecessary.

Comment: @Jyrki: We could flip a coin about that. :-)

Comment: If we are talking suggested edits, then if several of the user´s edits are rejected, they will not be able to suggest edits for some time.

Comment: Did you also inform the user? One can comment notify editors of a post; even though they are not suggested in autocomplete. Thus, one can right away leave a comment telling the editor that these edits should not be done. They may be receptive to this, if not one can still escalate.

Comment: @quid Thank you, I will try that next time.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Several days ago, I rejected many of their edits, and then they didn't have any (that I saw) for a day, then they tried to do a massive amount of useless edits once again.

Comment: Yes, I tried several weeks ago to tell them that it pushes recent questions and answers off of the main page (this happened to something I had answered shortly before their spree, at the time). They apologized but obviously didn't care. This was a Borel-Cantelli retagging spree, if I recall.

Comment: IMHO, one should simply stop giving rep (or whatever reward) to edition of old posts. This stop people from hunting down old posts for rep/badge. People who edit old posts for a proper reason won't care about those reward in the first place.

Comment: @achille: Also retire the Archaeologist badge, in that case, and the Taxonomist badge. Or perhaps combine them into a Taxidermist badge for manually editing a tag that you created to 50 posts inactive for six months or more; also it comes with a 30 days suspension.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen we gotta save those DB bytes right, no one might ever want to find questions involving coin flipping to test their knowledge. I'm totally for that tag and don't give a toss (pun intended) if someone gets a badge for adding it. If there's coin flipping in the question, go for it.

Comment: @AlecTeal Regardless of whether the 'coin-flipping' tag should exist or not, the user in question has been adding it to every post tagged 'probability'.

Comment: I know the user, yesterday (Dec. 8) I had a flurry of edits of his in the edit review queue (tens of them). I lost my temper and after rejecting one of those I left him a comment (prefixed with his name, of course) asking him to stop doing meaningless edits. He immediately stopped.

Comment: wait WAS THIS ME? Martin Sleziak linked me from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32778/how-come-we-got-rid-of-the-tag-coin-but-not-dice-poker-etc). if so then i wasn't a badge hunter @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @AlexM. was this ME?

Comment: @BCLC If you're talking about (coin-flipping), using [the query mentioned here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56220045#56220045) I get 8 question where you added that tag. It was added 17 times by another user. (I should add that this does not include the questions which have since been deleted.)

Comment: @BCLC: That comment of mine was from December 2015. Do you think I still remember? Come on!