# How come we got rid of the tag 'coin' but not 'dice', 'poker', etc?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Sounds like the tags [dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice), [poker](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poker) and [coin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coin) just fall under probability (or I guess 'permutations' or 'combinations'). I recall we got rid of [coin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coin) some years ago.

eg this [Expected Value : Poker](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916693/expected-value-poker)

I think dice and poker should be done away with for same reason as coin.

**Edit 1**: Unless there's for example some graph theory or game theory use for those or something. Maybe poker I get. Same with chess. But why is [dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) ok while [coin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coin) isn't?

**Edit 2**: Martin Sleziak linked this  [User adding irrelevant tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/user-adding-irrelevant-tags) in comments below. I think the user was me. Lol.

Comment: In addition to those there's the more generic [card-games](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games) tag.

Comment: I was only able to find a single questions which was tagged (coin) and that question is now deleted: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1873620/revisions Do you have some other examples of posts which had the tag (coin)? Maybe you have the tag (coin-flipping) in mind which was mentioned here: [User adding irrelevant tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22117). (And it was created and removed around the time of that post.) I left a few comments related to (coin) and (coin-flipping) in the [Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2020/11/21).

Comment: A coin is a 2-sided die, in some sense :/

Comment: @MartinSleziak indeed, I meant coin-flipping

Comment: @TheSimpliFire oh yeah and even 'gambling' https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3916693/3

Comment: @MartinSleziak wait i think the the 'user adding irrelevant tags' thing is me lol

Comment: @FearfulSymmetry amen to that! wait...are you saying coin is bad because it is subsumed under die/dice? or are you saying coin is bad if and only if die/dice is bad? or what?

Comment: you were  only the user with the second most tag additions for the coin-flipping tag (some anonymous user ID seems to be 1st...?); [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRIET.png) is the output of [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1146497/number-of-tag-additions-per-user?tagname=coin-flipping) SEDE query that Martin made (found it in the tagging chatroom)

Comment: I guess what I meant to say is: if we're going to have all the 'specialized' tags (dice, poker, etc.), certainly we don't need 'coin', as coin is the $n=2$ case of dice.

Comment: @FearfulSymmetry but wait so what is your opinion of the specialised tags? or you don't really have any particular opinion? or what?

Comment: I have no opinion really; I just think that $\text{coin}\subset \text{dice}$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor oh ok so i guess it wasn't me. lol. or maybe it was a combination of me and the other person

Comment: @FearfulSymmetry ah ayt. thanks for the clarification

Comment: I decided to propose a tag synonym making [dice] map to [probability].